# Window location href change does not reload

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

**UPDATE**

I have some code that checks if the user is visiting my site via a mobile device. If they do, then I do a simple redirect. However, when the code executes I am not redirected. I know the code runs but no redirect occurs. Instead, some of my javascript code breaks, though no errors appear on my console. You would think Moore's law would have mercy on me.

What's wrong and how could I fix this?

```
// device.mobile() give me true on false on whether device is mobile
if (device.mobile()) {
   window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com";
}
```

Comment: you clearly have a syntax error

Comment: Ugh, it's been a long week. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question as code still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its wrong address  use this

> "https://itunes.apple.com";

note: best way for checking your javascript code is javascript console 
(Alt-Shift+j in google chrome)

Comment: I did check console, but no errors appeared. I updated my answer slightly as the code still does not work.

Comment: did you checked the device.mobile() return ?
console.log(device.mobile());

Comment: I'm going to re-ask this question as I think it's extending beyond my original question.